# Projection image of a normalizer

Tags: group-theory

Let $U \leq G = A \times B$. Then $\pi_X(N_G(U) )= X \cap N_G(U)$ for $X = A, B$

So let $x \in A \cap N_G(U)$ then $x\in A$ and $x\in N_G(U)$. Clearly $\pi_A(x) = x$. Thus $x \in \pi_A(N_G(U))$

I'm not sure how to prove the other inclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim is wrong. Let $H$ be any group with trivial center, e.g. $H = S_3$. Then for $G = H \times H$ and $U = \{ (h,h) : h \in H \}$ we have $N_G(U) = U$ but $\pi_H(U) = H$, whereas $H \cap U$ is trivial.